# Given any alphabet ∑, the language L over ∑* described by {x: any symbol of x differs from the previous symbol} is regular

Tags: regex

This was given as a challenge problem during one of my lectures

Given any alphabet ∑, the language L over ∑* described by {x: any symbol of x differs from the previous symbol} is regular

How do I prove that this is true or false? The way I thought about it was that x could be any "symbol" and therefore the language could contain an infinite number of some "symbols", and since it is infinite it is therefore not regular, is this correct?

Comment: Your best bet is to try and represent it as some finite automaton.  You have a start state and a number of accept states equal to the symbols in the language `∑`.  The state you are currently in represents a symbol, and has transitions to the states to all other symbols in the language.  If you try to transition to the state you are already in (have two identical symbols in a row), you transfer to a non-accepting state that loops all symbols to itself (a sink)

Comment: I'd have to double check, but I'm pretty sure that an infinite alphabet would imply that the language is not regular (Because it cannot be represented by a DFA).  It's probably safe for you to assume a finite alphabet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is to try and represent it as some finite automaton. You have a start state and a number of accept states equal to the symbols in the language `∑`. The state you are currently in represents a symbol, and has transitions to the states to all other symbols in the language. If you try to transition to the state you are already in (have two identical symbols in a row), you transfer to a non-accepting state that loops all symbols to itself (a sink)

Here's a quick illustration with `∑ = {A, B, C}`

[image: DFA]